# Windows keeps turning off notifications for one particular app

Tags: windows, notifications

I am using Windows 10 Home. Notifications work normally for most apps, except one: the Mailbird email client.

Every few days (the exact period seems random, it can be anything between a day and a week) the notifications are disabled for Mailbird in Windows Settings. When I notice it's happened again, I go into Windows Settings -> Notifications and Actions Settings and turn them from Off to On. Then they will work correctly again and the cycle continues.

I've contacted the Mailbird developers and they said it's not something on their end. I don't know what else to try.

I've been having this problem for at least a year and it's very annoying. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If it's true that Mailbird isn't doing it, then it must be some other installed product. Try to guess, perhaps your security software.

Comment: Is the issue happened in specific time every day or every week? If it happened on in specific time, is there any related task scheduled in Task Scheduler?

Comment: As far as security goes, I only use Windows Defender. No, it doesn't happen at a specific time, it seems random. I thought maybe it's a Windows feature, maybe I'm disabling the notifications in some way when I click on them to open them, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: If the Mailbird developers are wrong about this not being their problem, you could clean-uninstall it using [Revo Uninstaller Free](https://www.revouninstaller.com/products/revo-uninstaller-free/) and reinstall. You would need to redo its configuration.

Comment: Does the Mailbird client have options to turn on and off notifications? I've had something like that happen to me... all I had to do was change the notification settings in the program I was having the problem with...

Comment: Yes, Mailbird has options to turn notifications on or off. They have always been set to "on". The issue is with the Windows notification settings.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to run the SFC and check for the issue.

System File checker (SFC) scan is done to check if there are any corrupted system files that could be causing this issue.

Refer to these steps to perform a SFC scan:

a) Press `Windows key + X`, select Command prompt (Admin) to bring up an elevated command prompt.

b) In the command prompt type the following command: `sfc/scannow` and press enter.

Keep us posted if you face any issues on windows in future. We will be glad to help you.

If still the same problem then you try this method.

You can choose to turn email notification on or off. Turning them on allows you to see a message pop up from your system tray.

When you click on the notification it opens that email in Mailbird when it is minimized or not the active window.

To adjust your email notification settings:

1. Go to the Mailbird menu in the top left of the main window.
2. Select "Settings"
3. Click the "General" tab
4. Check or un-check the "Notifications: Show tray notification when receiving a message" box.

[check first image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUCqD.png)

You will see the new email message notification in your system tray that you can click on when Mailbird is minimized to open that new message.

[second image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3M241.png)

Comment: Of course the Mailbird setting was already turned on. The problem is with the Windows notification settings turning off. I tried the SFC scan, it did report finding some problems but checking the log they don't seem to be related to Mailbird. I'll keep an eye on the issue, see if it will still happen and report back.

Comment: you can update your windows 10 and then reinstall Mailbird on your pc